# Linux printing using lp command

Tags: rhel, printing, lp

We are going to move our system from AIX to Red Hat. AIX had a command to start on the second page of the print file. What is a command to start on the second page of a print file?

I tried the following in c shell :

```
setenv LPU1C "lp -d LPX1 -o cpi=17 -o lpi=12 -o page-right=24 -H resume -P2-"
```

The reason why it starts on the second page is for line printers.

Is there a command to set the number of lines to print?  AIX had an option to set print up to 65 lines and then start a new page.

Comment: It looks like it may not be possible with the `lp` command but it looks like you can probably get this functionality by using the `pr` command and piping it into `lp`

Comment: Thanks Jessse_b my reports are starting at page 2.  Next challenge is to set lines per page like the AIX.